# Composer Timeout When Extracting Archive

Tags: laravel, composer-php, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

I've recently run into an issue when running `composer install`. Specially when installing the `phpunit/phpunit` library. I've tried clearing the `composer` cache, removing the `vendor` folder, reinstalling my dev environment, running the command with elevated privileges, and increasing the `timeout` but nothing seems to be working.

Specially, when I run `composer create-project` or `composer install` all the packages are downloaded and installed without issue. But when it gets to `phpunit/phpunit` it hangs during extraction and eventually times out, with following error

```
Install of phpunit/phpunit failed
The following exception is caused by a process timeout
```

```
[Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessTimedOutException]
  The process "'/usr/local/bin/unzip' -qq '/home/vagrant/code/sites/*****/vendor/composer/tmp-9621203db1563
  410535b21d5fa51d984' -d '/home/vagrant/code/sites/*****/vendor/composer/ee7cafdb'" exceeded the timeout o
  f 300 seconds.
```

I have been able to run this command many times in the past, without any problem, this is only a recent issue.

My current dev environment is:

```
VirtualBox: 6.1.32
Vagrant: 2.2.19
Homestead: laravel/homestead (virtualbox, 12.0.0)
Composer: 2.25
Windows: 11
```

Any help is much appreciated. I've been stuck on this problem for nearly two days now, with no luck.

Comment: You have a lot of virtualization, VirtualBox + Vagrant + Homestead... you should be using WSL (because you have W11) and Docker and that's it... either way, just to be sure everything else is good, can you do `composer install --no-dev` so you only install `required` and see if that passes correctly?